# req.query returning null value?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

Using nodejs & running the following query - can anyone tell me why the id is returning null?

The below runs the initial query, inserting information into the track table. However, app crashes on second half of query with error message that vinyl_id is null.

```
app.post('/addtrack', (req, res)=>{
  let id = req.query.bid; 
  let name = req.body.tname; 
  let writer = req.body.twrite; 
  let length = req.body.tlength; 

  let inserttrack = ` INSERT INTO track(track_title, track_writer, track_length)
                      VALUES(?,?,?);

                      SET @tid = LAST_INSERT_ID(); 
                      
                      INSERT INTO vinyl_track(vinyl_id, track_id)
                      VALUES(?, @tid);`;

  connection.query(inserttrack, [name, writer, length, id], (err, rows)=>{
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log(id);
  });
  res.redirect('addtrack'); 
});
```

For reference I can see it is pulling the corresponding record from the database as the URL is showing, e.g. /vinylinfo?bid=5

Expecting the query to execute & records added to the database.

Comment: Could you please the full error message?

Comment: is the url vinylinfo or addtrack ? Also append console for req.query